# Change inside the class is not reflecting outside the class

Tags: python, class

```
>>> poi = 1

>>> class my_class():
     def __init__(self,poi):
         self.poi=poi
         for h in range(0,10):
              self.poi +=  1
              poi = self.poi
         print(self.poi)          

>>> my_class(0)
>>> 10
Out[68]: <__main__.my_class at 0x1ae14d7c400>

>>> poi
Out[69]: 1
```

Here I want to change the variable `poi`. I want the change to happen inside the class and I want the change to be reflected outside the class.When I print `self.poi` it prints 10. But when I print `poi` it still says the initial value 1, meaning the change is not reflected outside the class. What should I do to make it reflect outside the class?

Comment: What should be the purpose? Why do you want to change an global scope variable? Also I recommend you read something about the scope of variables

Comment: @BjörnB Actually, I have a big code, I tried simplifying the problem with this code. And yes, I know `self.poi` is a local variable inside the class. I just want to know how to make it assigned to my global variable `poi`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `poi` declared as a constant, thus I would not be keep changing it where it is, but if you really want to, run declare `poi` as global. Eg:

```py
...
global poi
poi = self.poi
...
```

However...
Consider putting `poi` at the top level of your class, like so:

```py
class my_class():
     poi = 1
     def __init__(self):
         for h in range(0,10):
              self.poi +=  1
         print(self.poi)
```

This way your instance will have an incremented value, but the class constant will remain the same.

Comment: But I don't want the class constant to remain the same. I want it to have the same value as the instance